# NodeJS - Is it possible to have two separate Clusters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, cluster-computing, global

**TL;DR**

Is it possible to have two different cluster masters that aren't a shared global? Such as making a new instance `myCluster = new cluster()`?

### The longer version

After using the new cluster module in NodeJS for some time, I've come across the problem of two separate clusters overlapping. Two different libraries (npm packages) access the same cluster master, as *the cluster module is a global in the current running process*, no matter where you `require` it from.

> Calling `cluster.workers` from any library will list every worker spawned by every library.

Everyone is going nuts over how easy and how much more efficient it is, but after having come across the issue of two libraries using the same cluster, I'm worried about one interfering with the other by using some of the global cluster functions, such as `cluster.disconnect()`, or accessing the global workers object `cluster.workers`. I understand that it's a fairly single-use case module, "create a self-sustainable cluster of disposable workers that can be easily restarted with a watchdog".

But it's the easiest solution for multi-threaded tasks, and sugarcoats a lot of the bother with `child_process`. What if two libraries decided it was necessary to use `cluster`, but didn't go through the effort of keeping track of which workers belong to them, and instead call a cheeky

```
Object.values(cluster.workers).forEach(worker => worker.kill())
```

as their cleanup?

**Is it possible to have two different "instances" or "namespaces" for clusters**, as so not to interfere with any other cluster masters? Or is the cluster module just a global variable that you must accept?

I've delved into the documentation, but from what I can tell there is no way to create a new cluster instance by calling `myCluster = new cluster()` or pass some unique identity to forked workers. I find it surprising that there is no obvious solution to this problem, especially considering that it targets enterprise applications, where such problems should not exist.

The trend (and has been for a while) in programming is to keep away from global instances, and create self-sufficient instances that are only aware of what they need to know, so called "dumb-components". Cluster is a fairly new addition to NodeJS, have they just decided to half-implement a great feature?

I would be very grateful for you thoughts or workarounds on the subject. Right now I'm creating a library that could heavily benefit from distribution of tasks, however I don't want to dirty up the global cluster of the package dependant. Should I resort back to low-level `child_process`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Answering my own question

After switching to the lower-level `child_process` module, I have **reverted** back to using `cluster` for one simple reason. Node.js's `--inspect` debugger.

After a lot of pain debugging another package, I traced the error back to a dependency that was my own library implementing the `child_process` approach. It was forking a `child-process` using the inherited `execArgs` from the parent process, meaning the `child_process` was trying to bind to the *same* inspector port as the parent process, failing silently and crashing.

While my first workaround was generating a random free (assigned by OS) debug port for the `child_process`, this was a valid workaround but posed its own problems. Foremostly, the process would have to be manually attached to a debugger by copying the unique port each time.

VS Code has a magical `autoAttachChildProcesses` that discovers forked processes but **only when using `cluster`**, at least in my case. It seems that `cluster` has some sugar-coating around the forking process, making it more discoverable and adaptable during debugging, or perhaps VS Code just listens exclusively for `cluster.fork()`. I have given in to the downside of making my worker visible to the entire application in favour of a more robust experience for users.

This is annoying behaviour that has an open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9435

---

My conclusion is that the cluster module is there for a more unified forking experience with more intelligent process handling and discovery, packages will just have to respect to never touch `cluster.workers` or similar global functions, and instead, maintain an array of their own workers returned by `cluster.fork()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well no. Or yes.

See, since clustering in node terms means forking the current process, there is no cluster actually - just a list of forks = workers.

But: you can fork and require the script (or if-else into a block) you want to have the fork as a worker and save that new worker into your own array = cluster/fork_list.

I have simple support module that separates the worker script (and simply loads different scripts + handles communication): [runworker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/runworker)

Comment: This is what I was afraid of... Forking or not (you can set a custom script to start using Cluster), there should be an option to create a localized instance that maintains its own array of workers. There is no reason in my eyes to have it global. My current solution at the moment is creating my own "cluster" class that maintains its own list of workers and manages them using `child_process`.

Comment: The http server and others use the global cluster, to handle load balance and distribute the one used port to the forks. There are some other modules relying on this. As said: it is all about forking the current process, not starting other scripts. "clustering". I believe I have seen modules on NPM actually managing clusters.